# Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:/jpaContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 
 <filter>
  <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
 
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </servlet>
 
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/pdfs/**</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/images/**</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 
 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

I was adding security to my demo application, (user-login) by using :[this tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5//helloworld.html) , I am getting error as: `Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!`

I have added my web.xml, Later i found [this tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5//hellomvc.html), then error was coming: `No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined`. In the tutorial they explained

> The MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer will automatically register the springSecurityFilterChain Filter for every URL in your application. If Filters are added within other WebApplicationInitializer instances we can use @Order to control the ordering of the Filter instances.
>   I didnot understand the above message please help me with this

Comment: When i remove                                                                                         `<!--  <context-param> -->
<!--   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> -->
<!--   <param-value>classpath:/jpaContext.xml</param-value> -->
<!--  </context-param> -->

<!--  <listener> -->
<!--   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> -->
<!--  </listener> -->`, this then **spring login** works but my application dont work

Comment: Can you show us your complete web.xml?

Comment: @Arpit i have added my web.xml

Comment: Can you try changing the property name of context-param : `<context-param>
  <param-name>anothername</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:/jpaContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>`

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `fitTrackerServlet` servlet as:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time .That worked, but when in am restarting the server its directly going to my application without login, shall i have to add @order annotation in my filters/urls

Comment: You want to go through `SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` filter while login?

Comment: Hi, i want each page of my application should not be accessible before login

Comment: When i am adding the following method : `public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer
      extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }
}`, its showing the same error `check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!`, this will Automatically register the springSecurityFilterChain Filter for every URL in myapplication

Comment: In which filter you are writing the logic for the same?

Comment: I am adding spring security through annotations, i didn't added any filter because the annotations will take care of it